# How to find reason for warning 'Could not load device from the device dictionary'

Tags: xconnect, configuration, certificate

I've setup a separate CD environment for Sitecore 9.0.1 and upon starting the website, I see 1 exception in the log files that is logged as a warning.

I've made sure that the client xConnect certificate was installed and the thumbprint is correctly in the ConnectionStrings.config.

How can I fix this warning?

```
    8248 09:13:29 WARN  Could not load device 'ea07cc63-1d43-437e-86b8-9fec30bae95f' from the device dictionary.
Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.XdbUnavailableException
Message: xDB unavailable
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Dictionaries.XConnectDeviceDictionary.LoadAs[T](Object key)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.AverageCounterExtensions.MeasureMilliseconds[T](AverageCounter counter, Func`1 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.ReferenceDataDictionary`2.Get(TKey key, LookupStrategy strategy)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureDevice.LoadDevice(Guid deviceId)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.Get[TEntity](IXdbContext context, IEntityReference`1 reference, ExpandOptions expandOptions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<GetDevice>b__1(IXdbContext xdbContext)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
```

Comment: Based on the error  it seems Sitecore cannot connect to xdb. Have you checked your connection strings and certificates and validated xdb is reachable?

Comment: I can open all 4 xConnect websites in the browser (showing the timestamp). The certificate has 'cannot be verified up to trusted certification authority'. But the client certificate in ConnectionStrings is correct and has the same thumbprint as on the xConnect sites.

Comment: Is this issue fixed?
I am also facing the same issue. Phaneendra

Answer (score 1):

Could not load device 'ea07cc63-1d43-437e-86b8-9fec30bae95f'  - This ID is the analytics cookie id set in your browser. Sitecore is trying to search for above id in xDB to find if  you are the existing visitor or new visitor.

sitecore was unable to connect to xDB due to incorrect credentials in your connection string config file for xdb.collection.shrdmanager database.

Try to connect to xdb.collection.shrdmanager DB using '(yoursiteprefix)_collectionuser' from SQl server.

Make sure that SQL browser and SQL server agent were running in services.msc